# mongoose bulk insert error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

I am woking on `node.js` and I am using `mongoose` bulk insert method  i.e. `model.collection.insert` to insert data in MongoDB. When this method executes it gives below error :

But data insert Successfully in the database. Can some tell me why i am getting this error?

```
{ [MongoError: write operation failed]
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'write operation failed',
  driver: true,
  code: 11000,
  writeErrors: 
   [ { code: [Getter],
       index: [Getter],
       errmsg: [Getter],
       getOperation: [Function],
       toJSON: [Function],
       toString: [Function] },
     { code: [Getter],
       index: [Getter],
       errmsg: [Getter],
       getOperation: [Function],
       toJSON: [Function],
       toString: [Function] },
     { code: [Getter],
       index: [Getter],
       errmsg: [Getter],
       getOperation: [Function],
       toJSON: [Function],
       toString: [Function] },
     { code: [Getter],
       index: [Getter],
       errmsg: [Getter],
       getOperation: [Function],
       toJSON: [Function],
       toString: [Function] },
     { code: [Getter],
       index: [Getter],
       errmsg: [Getter],
       getOperation: [Function],
       toJSON: [Function],
       toString: [Function] },
     { code: [Getter],
       index: [Getter],
       errmsg: [Getter],
       getOperation: [Function],
       toJSON: [Function],
       toString: [Function] },
     { code: [Getter],
       index: [Getter],
       errmsg: [Getter],
       getOperation: [Function],
       toJSON: [Function],
       toString: [Function] },
     { code: [Getter],
       index: [Getter],
       errmsg: [Getter],
       getOperation: [Function],
       toJSON: [Function],
       toString: [Function] },
     { code: [Getter],
       index: [Getter],
       errmsg: [Getter],
       getOperation: [Function],
       toJSON: [Function],
       toString: [Function] },
     { code: [Getter],
       index: [Getter],
       errmsg: [Getter],
       getOperation: [Function],
       toJSON: [Function],
       toString: [Function] },
     { code: [Getter],
       index: [Getter],
       errmsg: [Getter],
       getOperation: [Function],
       toJSON: [Function],
       toString: [Function] },
     { code: [Getter],
       index: [Getter],
       errmsg: [Getter],
       getOperation: [Function],
       toJSON: [Function],
       toString: [Function] },
     { code: [Getter],
       index: [Getter],
       errmsg: [Getter],
       getOperation: [Function],
       toJSON: [Function],
       toString: [Function] },
     { code: [Getter],
       index: [Getter],
       errmsg: [Getter],
       getOperation: [Function],
       toJSON: [Function],
       toString: [Function] },
     { code: [Getter],
       index: [Getter],
       errmsg: [Getter],
       getOperation: [Function],
       toJSON: [Function],
       toString: [Function] },
     { code: [Getter],
       index: [Getter],
       errmsg: [Getter],
       getOperation: [Function],
       toJSON: [Function],
       toString: [Function] },
     { code: [Getter],
       index: [Getter],
       errmsg: [Getter],
       getOperation: [Function],
       toJSON: [Function],
       toString: [Function] },
     { code: [Getter],
       index: [Getter],
       errmsg: [Getter],
       getOperation: [Function],
       toJSON: [Function],
       toString: [Function] },
     { code: [Getter],
       index: [Getter],
       errmsg: [Getter],
       getOperation: [Function],
       toJSON: [Function],
       toString: [Function] },
     { code: [Getter],
       index: [Getter],
       errmsg: [Getter],
       getOperation: [Function],
       toJSON: [Function],
       toString: [Function] },
     { code: [Getter],
       index: [Getter],
       errmsg: [Getter],
       getOperation: [Function],
       toJSON: [Function],
       toString: [Function] },
     { code: [Getter],
       index: [Getter],
       errmsg: [Getter],
       getOperation: [Function],
       toJSON: [Function],
       toString: [Function] },
     { code: [Getter],
       index: [Getter],
       errmsg: [Getter],
       getOperation: [Function],
       toJSON: [Function],
       toString: [Function] },
     { code: [Getter],
       index: [Getter],
       errmsg: [Getter],
       getOperation: [Function],
       toJSON: [Function],
       toString: [Function] } ] }
```

Here is the Code:

mOfferCake.collection.insert(jsonArr, {
                            continueOnError: true,
                            keepGoing: true
                        }, onInsert);

1)
mOfferCake is model and below is the code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var offerCakeSchema = new Schema({
    offer_id: {
        type: Number,
        unique: true
    }
});

var datetime = new Date();
var mm = datetime.getMonth() + 1;
if (mm < 10) {
    mm = '0' + mm;
}
var dd = datetime.getDate();
if (dd < 10) {
    dd = '0' + dd;
}
var yyyy = datetime.getFullYear();
var collectionName = 'MX_' + yyyy + '_' + mm + '_' + dd;
module.exports = mongoose.model(collectionName, offerCakeSchema);
```

2)
jsonArr is array of JSON object

3) onInsert is callback function

```
function onInsert(err, docs) {
if (err) {
console.log(err);
}
else {
    console.error("Cron bulk insert Successfully");
}
```

}

node version : v4.5.0
mongoose version : 4.6.5

Answer (score 1):

> code: 11000,

E11000 means duplicate key error index.

You probably inserting documents which `_id` already exists in the collection.

Comment: Every time I am inserting new set of data and _id is auto generated